# An inequalities on order statistics

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X=(X_1,...,X_k)$ be a square integrable random vector in $\mathbb R^k$ and $X_{(j)}$ the $j$-th ordered value of $X$, i.e., $X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq ... \leq X_{(k)}$. Prove (or disprove) that
$$ \sum_{j=1}^k \mathbb E (X_{(j)}) ^2 \geq \sum_{j=1}^k \mathbb E (X_{j}) ^2. $$

Comment: in the case n equally probable outcomes I think it is equivalent to maximizing $\sum x_i y_{\pi(i)}$ (where x and y are two possible outcomes) and according to the re-arrangement inequality this happens when you put them both in the same order.  if you agree that this is a reasonble approach you can see mike steele's excellent cauchy-schwartz book for the inequality.

Comment: The rearrangement inequality can definitely help proving this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an answer roger if you have already done it?

Comment: I got the inequality is the other way round...

Comment: I've proved it for $k=2$, it's quite straitforward. Precisely, we have
$$ \mathbb E(X_{(1)})^2+ \mathbb E(X_{(2)})^2 = \mathbb E(X_1)^2 + \mathbb E(X_2)^2 + 2 \mathbb E[(X_1 - X_2) \mathbf 1 \{X_1 \geq X_2 \}] \mathbb E[(X_2 - X_1) \mathbf 1 \{X_2 > X_1 \}]. $$
I thought of doing some sort of induction proof for the general case but I couldn't do it yet.

Comment: @Lost1 How did you get to the reverse inequality?

Comment: I dont understand your equality. What is $E(X_{(1)})$?

Comment: In the case $k=2$, $X_{(1)} = \min \{ X_1,X_2 \}$ and $X_{(2)} = \max \{X_1,X_2 \}$.

Comment: it seems like that i have made an error, though i still dont quite understand your equality.

Comment: OH I now understand Mike's comment. this is simply quadratic-arithmetic mean inequality in disguise. all you need to is that $\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_{(i)}) = n E(X_{i})$. Let each term on the left hand side $a_i$, and $E(X_i)=c$ then $\sum a_i  = n c$. notice $c$ is the arithmetic mean of the left hand side. Then the required inequality follows by Quadratic-arithmetic mean inequality.

Comment: $X_1,...,X_k$ are not necessarily iid and there is a square ($\mathbb E (X_i)^2$) but thanks anyway.